# hyperref, lualatex and unicode bookmarks issue (garbled page numbers in AR for Linux)

Tags: hyperref, luatex

I have text with some non-ascii characters in chapters, sections... which I'd like to see in bookmarks displayed correctly. I noticed that,

- If I run `xelatex`, everything is fine, no need to set `\hypersetup{unicode=true}` to get this working
- If I run `lualatex`, I have these issues:

  1. If `unicode=false`, then bookmarks containing non-ascii characters have strange unreadable symbols instead of those chars, but everything else is fine
  2. If `unicode=true`, then bookmarks are just fine, but page numbers in resulting PDF file are garbled in Adobe Reader 9 on Linux (and Okular shows some strange symbols in bookmark pane too)

Is it a driver issue? Any suggestion how to overcome this problem?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{hyperref} 
%\hypersetup{unicode=true}

\begin{document}  

\section{Test 1 čćžđš}    
Some text.\clearpage  

\section{Test 2 šđžćč}    
Some text.

\end{document}
```

**A notice**: I tried to post this question on comp.text.tex earlier, but something went wrong and it didn't show up. Anyway, if the post shows up later, I'll post the link here.

Comment: it _is_ on c.t.t.

Comment: I can't find it :(

Comment: the answer from Heiko is also there

Comment: Is there a link? And if you're referring to this post (http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/a2661d8af7d1c513/74ec6d33d1e1d725?lnk=gst&q=text+garbled), no, there is no answer which solves this issue.

Comment: @Meho: yes, it would be great if you would post that as answer and accept it.

Comment: @Stefan, if you say it's OK, then so be it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I received an email from Heiko suggesting that I try auto pdfencoding which worked indeed. So, the solution is:

```
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}
```

And corrected MWE from above:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{%
    pdfencoding=auto,
    pdfauthor={Author Test ČĆŽĐŠ},
    pdftitle={Title test, čćžđš}
    }

\begin{document}  

\section{Test 1 čćžđš}    
Some text.\clearpage  

\section{Test 2 šđžćč}    
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Complete Heiko's answer can be found on [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/6fYmcVMbSbQ/discussion).

Answer (score 3):

Even with pdfencoding=auto, I had trouble with either the bookmarks or the metadata or the page numbers. But all three come out perfectly if I use the [navigator](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/navigator) package rather than hyperref.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that metadata gets messed up sometimes. The solution might be to use `\hypersetup` locally, that is, e.g., `\hypersetup{pdfencoding=utf8}` before specifying author name, title and other metadata stuff, then `\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}` after that, to get bookmarks and numbers displayed correctly.

Comment: This solution breaks my metadata. Putting `pdfencoding=auto` on first place in the package option (`\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}`) does everything right. Is that kind of a bug in hyperref? Shouldn't "auto" be default?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi not sure if you're still active here, but this fixed the problem for me. Would you consider posting it as a separate answer? It seems a shame it's buried in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `pdfencoding=auto` on first place in the package option (`\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}`) does everything right.