# What hyperref options should be used for correct Unicode output?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, luatex, unicode, preamble

I am trying to work out which `hyperref` options allow all Unicode characters to display properly, and whether XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and pdfLaTeX have different configuration requirements. The [`hyperref` documentation](https://tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) helps with several problems, but there are a few ambiguities. Given the ubiquity of this package, it seems worthwhile to straighten these out:

- The `unicode` option is required to ensure that LuaLaTeX displays bookmarks and PDF properties correctly. On the other hand, there is [a thread from 2009](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2009-December/015132.html) suggesting that the `unicode` option can somehow break with XeTeX. As far as I can tell, it simply has no effect on the latter, and can be used safely with all engines.

  There are also [indications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79897/non-ascii-characters-are-not-displayed-in-hyperrefs-pdftitle-bug-in-the-unico) that using `unicode` as a package option can be more effective than leaving it for `\hypersetup`, but the manual implies that these approaches should have the same effect.
- It is [sometimes suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24445/hyperref-lualatex-and-unicode-bookmarks-issue-garbled-page-numbers-in-ar-for-l) that `pdfencoding=auto` or `pdfencoding=unicode` should also be enabled for LuaTeX (it is [enabled automatically for XeTeX](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README)). In my testing, the `unicode` option appears to be sufficient, but I wonder whether there are any situations it does not cover.
- [Another thread from 2009](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2009-December/015145.html) and a [closed StackExchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38615/xelatex-hyperref-and-page-breaking) suggest that `setpagesize` should be set to `false` with XeTeX. I cannot seem to find any solid examples where this makes a difference, and I wonder whether this has been fixed.

This is what I am using so far, but I would be grateful to know whether any of these are redundant, or indeed whether there is anything I am missing that improves the final PDF:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            unicode=true,
            pdfauthor={AUTHOR NAME},
            pdftitle={TITLE},
            pdfsubject={SUBJECT},
            pdfkeywords={KEYWORD;KEYWORD},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
```